# How to easily uncheck all checkboxes with Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

I have a list of checkboxes, created using [`collection_check_boxes`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_check_boxes).

When testing this in a feature/integration test, using Capybara, and want to "normalize" the page by unchecking them all, then checking the ones I want checked:

```
within_fieldset('Product') do
  # Reset all checkboxes for a level playingfield.
  # What to do?

  # Mark checkboxes for products enabled
  products.each do |product|
    check products
  end
end
```

This is in a so-called PageObject, hence I want to somewhat generic: were this in the actual test, I would know which fields were checked and uncheck them. But this more generic helper has no such knowledge.

I've tried something along the lines of `find('input[type=checkbox]').all {|checkbox| uncheck(checkbox) }`, which should work but seems rather convoluted for the task at hand, not?

Is there not some `uncheck_all()?` that I missed, in Capybara? Is it a common pattern to "Reset" a form in capybara to a blank state before starting to fill_in forms?

Comment: I think that your solution is not convoluted. But if you are going to use it heavily, then you can pack it into a function and call it whenever you need it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
all('input[type=checkbox]').each do |checkbox|
 if checkbox.checked? then 
  checkbox.click
 end
end
```

Comment: I have tested it on my system..it is working perfectly fine as you expected @berkes.Let me know if it still differs from your requirement.

Comment: Can you please accept this answer if it solved your issue otherwise let me know the issue.

Answer (score 3):

This is almost identical to your solution, but might be slightly more legible, and I think also works with custom JS checkboxes.  As far as I know there isn't anything like an `uncheck_all` method.

`all("input[type='checkbox']").each{|box| box.set('false')}`